# How to bind ItemsControl in DataGrid behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, itemscontrol

I have this custom vertical scrollbar that is defined in UserControl.Resources, it has a ItemsControl in it called 'ItemsSelected'.

What I would to do is bind it to the DependencyProperty ItemsControlObject in behavior DataGridSelectionChanged. The example binding does not work but shows what I'd like to achieve. What am I missing to bind ItemsSelected?

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=ItemsSelected'. 
BindingExpression:(no path); 
DataItem=null; 
target element is 'DataGridSelectionChanged' (HashCode=43407976); 
target property is 'ItemsControlObject' (type 'ItemsControl')

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Grid>
                ...
                <!-- BEGIN -->
                <ItemsControl Name="ItemsSelected" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.MarkerCollection}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Width="18" Height="4"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
                <!-- END -->
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" >
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="18" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Name="gridUsers" Background="Transparent">
        <DockPanel>
            <DataGrid Name="GenericDataGrid">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <helpers:DataGridSelectionChanged ItemsControlObject="{Binding ElementName=ItemsSelected}" />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    ...
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[EDIT]

```
public static class ScrollBarMarkers
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarkersSelectedCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MarkersSelectedCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<double>), typeof(ScrollBarMarkers), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static ObservableCollection<double> GetMarkersSelectedCollection(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<double>)obj.GetValue(MarkersSelectedCollectionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMarkersSelectedCollection(ItemsControl obj, ObservableCollection<double> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MarkersSelectedCollectionProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you use this ControlTemplate in your DataGrid, which would make the ControlTemplate filled through Binding I think you need to specify `Path` in your Binding i.e. `<helpers:DataGridSelectionChanged ItemsControlObject="{Binding ElementName=ItemsSelected, Path=.}" />`

Comment: Unfortunately the same sort of error occurs: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=ItemsSelected'. BindingExpression:Path=.; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridSelectionChanged' (HashCode=20692948); target property is 'ItemsControlObject' (type 'ItemsControl')

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think the Binding is failing on finding the actual `DataContext`, instead of `ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.MarkerCollection}"` try `ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.MarkerCollection}"`.

Comment: You could be on to something here. MarkerCollection is actually a DependencyProperty under xmlns:helpers so I've changed that to: ItemsSource="{Binding Path=helpers:MarkerCollection}", however get System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'helpers:MarkerCollection' property not found on 'object' ''UsersViewModel'. BindingExpression:Path=helpers:MarkerCollection; DataItem='UsersViewModel'; target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable') I'll put DependencyProperty at the bottom of the question as an edit.

Comment: Just tried ItemsSource="{Binding Path=helpers:ScrollBarMarkers.MarkerCollection}" still got Error 40 message

Comment: I have an idea, why don't you try to put a Converter in your Binding and see what's passed in?

Comment: see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295374/dependencyproperty-registration-in-viewmodel)

Comment: I am a fool, with the MarkerCollection I should have created just a plain property instead of attached property. I have done this by creating a property in a class with a singleton pattern and tested it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing things like this stops the need for binding the actual ItemsControl

Here is the binding:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static helpers:MyClass.Instance}, Path=SelectedMarkers}">
```

Here is the class with singleton pattern

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static ObservableCollection<double> m_selectedMarkers = new ObservableCollection<double>();
    public ObservableCollection<double> SelectedMarkers
    {
        get
        {
            return m_selectedMarkers;
        }
        set
        {
            m_selectedMarkers = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private static MyClass m_Instance;
    public static MyClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_Instance == null)
            {
                m_Instance = new MyClass();
            }

            return m_Instance;
        }
    }

    private MyClass()
    {
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```